# ggplot in R: Dashed and solid lines wrongly assigned (legend and graph differ)

Tags: r, ggplot2, aes, legend

I'm creating a graph that shows my data as box plots with a thin solid line connecting the medians.
Then there's their thick solid regression line.
Additionally, I'm plotting 4 functions ("estimates"). These should be displayed as dashed lines.

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x=frequency, y=`velocity unipolar (m/s)`)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = map, color = loc_map))+ 
  stat_summary(fun=median, geom="line", aes(group=loc_map, color = loc_map))  + 
  stat_summary(fun=median, geom="point", aes(group=loc_map))+
  stat_poly_line(aes(group = loc_map, color = loc_map))+ 
  guides(color=guide_legend(title="Mapping location:"))+ 
  labs(x = "Heart rate (bpm)", y = "Velocity unipolar (m/s)")+
  stat_function(fun = fun.LA.vel, aes(color = "LA"), linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_function(fun = fun.LV.vel, aes(color = "LV"), linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_function(fun = fun.RA.vel, aes(color = "RA"), linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_function(fun = fun.RV.vel, aes(color = "RV"), linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

**How can I add a correct linetype legend?
In my tries dashed and solid were correctly assigned in the legend, but the other way round in the graph** (plus there's a strange blue part in the dashed-legend):

```
ggplot(data = dd, aes(x=frequency, y=`velocity unipolar (m/s)`)) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(group = map, color = loc_map))+ 
  stat_summary(fun=median, geom="line", aes(group=loc_map, color = loc_map))  + 
  stat_summary(fun=median, geom="point", aes(group=loc_map))+
  stat_poly_line(aes(group = loc_map, color = loc_map, linetype = "regression line"))+ 
  guides(color=guide_legend(title="Mapping location:"))+ 
  labs(x = "Heart rate (bpm)", y = "Velocity unipolar (m/s)")+
  geom_function(fun = fun.LA.vel, aes(color = "LA", linetype = "estimate")) +
  geom_function(fun = fun.LV.vel, aes(color = "LV", linetype = "estimate")) +
  geom_function(fun = fun.RA.vel, aes(color = "RA", linetype = "estimate")) +
  geom_function(fun = fun.RV.vel, aes(color = "RV", linetype = "estimate"))+
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c("solid", "dashed"),labels=c("regression line","estimate"))
```

[image]

Comment: You have put the values and labels round the wrong way in `scale_linetype_manual`. By default, ggplot will order the levels of a variable in alphabetical order. The two levels for linetype are "estimate" and "regression line" in that order. Just use `scale_linetype_manual(values = c('dashed', 'solid'))` without any labels.

Comment: Now the assignment is correct, but there's still a blue line underneath the dashed and solid lines in the legend. 
How did that happen?